# Verify() if testing method throws exception. Can we avoid try-catch?

Tags: c#, .net, moq, xunit

I have a test method:

```
[Fact]
public void Test001()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IValidator>();

    var sut = new Sut(mock.Object);

    try
    {
        Action a = () => sut.TestedMethod();

        a.Should().Throw<ArgumentException>();
    }
    catch { }

    mock.Verify(x => x.IsValid(), Times.Once);
}
```

and a `TestedMethod`:

```
public void TestedMethod()
{
    _ = _validator.IsValid();

    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

Is there any way to get rid of try-catch here?

However, when eliminating try-catch, naturally, the Verification always fails.

Is there any beautiful workaround?

Comment: Have you checked which exception you're getting in the try/catch?

Comment: ArgumentException

Comment: I would make my best not verifying the internals, because that could highly couple your tests to the implementation details. You may want to test the external behaviour only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use xunit's built-in `Throws` function (instead of FluentAssertion) then you don't need the `try-catch` block.

Simply just:

```
Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => sut.TestedMethod());
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

The `Assert.Throws` does not throw exception. It returns the captured exception to allow further assessment, like this:

```
var actualException = Assert.Throws<ArgumentException>(() => sut.TestedMethod());
Assert.Equal(expectedErrorMessage, actualExcepion.Message);
```

Since it does not throw exception the test can continue its execution with the `Verify` check

Comment: You didn`t understand the question. The problem is not to ensure that error is thrown. The problem is to verify that IsValid() was fired. It would be easy if the method would not throw exception. But as the method throws exception, the test crashes before Verify() is even hit.

Comment: @MaxHanin The Assert.Throws does not throw exception. It returns the thrown exception to allow further assessment. Since it does not throw exception the test can continue its execution with the Verify check.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thank you